# Unable to ever properly get Windows running under bootcamp

Tags: windows, macos, bsod, boot-camp

I have a late 2012 iMac I'm trying to get Windows 7/8/8.1 running on. I've tried all 3 versions, and nothing ever works. I'm pretty certain it's a driver problem - the OS installs fine and I can do most of the stuff I want to, but there's something wrong with how the drivers were installed. I've tried manually getting the latest drivers from Apple and running them after install AND letting bootcamp get them, and it never seems to work right. I have an old-ish copy of Windows 7 I tried to get working and I purchased a copy of Windows 8.1 and neither works right. After a while, the system starts getting slow and gets progressively slower. Then, depending on my luck, it'll either freeze indefinitely or BSoD with a varied message - something about watchdog, system_service_exception(?), or some other timeout. I'm really tired of this and what's most frustrating is that I can't find any solutions online. Very few people seem to deal with this, which is strange because I don't think I have very rare circumstances. Would anyone know anything that could help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide an example of the errors you get?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a type-II hypervisor like VMWare Fusion, Parallels Desktop or Oracle VirtualBox. These will add a layer of abstraction from the hardware and have their own base drivers which should address your problem. You get the added benefit of having OS X and Windows (or any other guest OS) running at the same time.

The biggest downside is the performance overhead of running an OS within an OS. So if performance is critical, this may not be the best solution for you.